# GridView different width childrens

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

My goal is to create an automatic form generator, so the user can add controls to the screen. And the controls must have different widths.

Example:

The user could add an `EditText` that will use the width of the screen and add a `CheckBox` after the `EditText` that would be placed below the `EditText`. And could also add a button or spinner that will use the rest of the width of the screen. The user can all all the controls desired.

How can i achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a gridview, you could use a TableLayout, which has multiple TableRow elements.

What's interesting is that the width of a column is defined by the width of the widest element in the column.

You can take a look at the TableLayout [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it such as `TableLayout` and also using lots of nested layouts.

The `TableLayout` way is probably the best and easiest way to implement what you're looking for.

If you want to dynamically change the layout depending on the width of the screen there are two ways.

**Method 1** Programmatically create the layouts instead of using xml layout files. this way you can do calculations and change things on the fly.

**Method 2** This is probably the way I would do it. Include different layout files for different screen densities, orientations and sizes.

Comment: i undestand, but i rather want to use way to add items till the width of the line is full, than do a breakline.
maybe i wasnt clear.

Comment: So dynamically change where the stuff appears depending on the width of the screen?

Comment: look above for dynamic layouts

Comment: yeap but its all dynamic, a button doesnt have the same width as a text field, by this i mean, maybe there could be 2 text fields, but if i select buttons there could be 4 buttons in a row, and so on...